# Map string from var1 to var2 (lookup)

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, variable, string

I want to do case insensitive lookup on `VAR2` based on the content of VAR1 that holds some parameters in the form `key`:`value`. If a `VAR1` `key` is present replace the value in VAR2.

For example for:

```
VAR1=tom:rich,LIAm:viki
VAR2=liam,albert,tom
```

I want the result will be:

```
VAR3='viki','albert','rich'
```

`VAR1` can be empty.

Comment: none of  the results in var3 exist in *both* var1 and var2; only "liam" exists in both...?

Comment: @JeffSchaller If I understand correctly OP wants to do a case insensitive lookup  on `VAR2` based on the content of `VAR1` that holds some parameters in the form `key:value`. If a `VAR1` key is present replace the value in `VAR2`.

Comment: I will use your frasing, it is clearer.

Comment: What shell are you using for this?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
VAR1=tom:rich,LIAm:viki
VAR2=liam,albert,tom

typeset -A map
for i ("${(@s(,))VAR1}") map[${(L)i%%:*}]=${i#*:}
out=()
for i ("${(@s(,))VAR2}") out+=${(qq)${map[${(L)i}]:-$i}}
VAR3=${(j(,))out}

printf '%s\n' "$VAR3"
```

Output:

```
'viki','albert','rich'
```

Same with `awk` (which you could use with `zsh`, or any Bourne-like shell like `bash`):

```
VAR1=tom:rich,LIAm:viki
VAR2=liam,albert,tom

export VAR1 VAR2
awk -v q=\' 'BEGIN {
  n = split(ENVIRON["VAR1"], a, ",")
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    k = v = a[i]
    sub(/:.*/, "", k)
    sub(/[^:]*:/, "", v)
    map[tolower(k)] = v
  }
  n = split(ENVIRON["VAR2"], a, ",")
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    k = tolower(a[i])
    out = out sep q (k in map ? map[k] : a[i]) q
    sep = ","
  }
  print out
}'
```

(one difference is that here we only enclose the values inside single quotes. If the value contains single quotes itself, like `foo'bar`, you get `'foo'bar'` while `zsh`'s `${(qq)var}` would give you `'foo'\''bar'`).

The `zsh` version allows any value for the items. They can contain any byte values including newline and NUL or an empty value. The `awk` one won't support NULs as those can't be stored in environment variables and depending on the implementation may choke of items containing bytes not forming valid characters.

Note that with both, `VAR2=` is understood as an empty list while `VAR2=,` is understood as a list of 2 empty elements, there's no way to express a list of one empty element.

Comment: Do you have a version of it in bash?

Comment: @Nir, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

A `bash` (4.0+) solution that builds up a `lookup` table (an associative array) using the lower-cased keys from `VAR1` and the associated values.  It then goes through the values in `VAR2` and builds `VAR3` with values from the lookup table, or from `VAR2` if there is no key in the lookup table corresponding to the current `VAR2` string.

```
VAR1=tom:rich,LIAm:viki
VAR2=liam,albert,tom

declare -A lookup

# build lookup table
while read -d , key_value; do
    # $key_value is a string like "tom:rich", separate these into key and value:
    IFS=: read key value <<<"$key_value"

    # add lower-cased key to table with value
    lookup[${key,,}]=$value
done <<<"$VAR1,"

# do lookups in table
while read -d , string; do
    # get newstring from table, but use $string if there's no entry:
    newstring=${lookup[${string,,}]:-$string}

    # add $newstring to VAR3, with a delimiting comma unless VAR3 is empty
    VAR3+="${VAR3:+,}'$newstring'"
done <<<"$VAR2,"

printf 'VAR3 = %s\n' "$VAR3"
```

This code outputs

```
VAR3 = 'viki','albert','rich'
```

This assumes that the values in `VAR1` and `VAR2` contains no newlines.

Comment: The problems with using `IFS=: read x y <<< ...` is that it wouldn't work for values that contain newline, and for `VAR1='x:foo:bar'` you'd get a `x -> foo:bar` mapping while for `VAR1=x:foo:` you'd get a `x -> foo` mapping. Without `-r`, you'd have unexpected behaviour with backslash. Note that using `<<<` also implies creating a temporary file each time with the content.

Comment: Not sure this really saves anything, but you can split VAR1 on comma with `IFS=, read -ra pairs <<<"$VAR1"`, then iterate over the pairs with `for var_value in "${pairs[@]}"`.

Comment: @glennjackman, that would split the *first line of VAR1* on comma, not the full value of VAR1 if it contains several lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` based on `RS` (record separator):

```
VAR3=$(awk '
         BEGIN{RS="[,\n]";FS=":";ORS=","} 
         NR==FNR{a[tolower($1)]=$2}
         NR>FNR{printf "%s\047%s\047",(FNR>1?ORS:""),(a[$1]?a[$1]:$1)}
       ' <(echo "$VAR1") <(echo "$VAR2") 
      )
```

The `a` array is filled with the content of `VAR1` with the key and value pair.
This one is used when parsing the second variable and value is replaced if an array entry exists.